# Nested if/then statement syntax

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I've been reading a bunch of answers around nesting if/then statements in Excel but I can't figure out how to fix a "formula parse error" in mine. From what I can tell and in my code editor the formula is correct. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

I have a row of cells that auto-generate a number 1-35 based on other values. I want the cell with the formula to pull data from another row based on what's the in row of numbers 1-35. It works when I test one at a time; it's the nesting that is causing the errors. Thanks!

```
=IF(E$167=1,C56,IF(E$167=2,D56,IF(E$167=3,E56,IF(E$167=4,F56,IF(E$167=5,G56,IF(E$167=6,H56,IF(E$167=7,I56,IF(E$167=8,J56,IF(E$167=9,K56,IF(E$167=10,L56,IF(E$167=11,M56,IF(E$167=12,N56,IF(E$167=13,O56,IF(E$167=14,P56,IF(E$167=15,Q56,IF(E$167=16,R56,IF(E$167=17,S56,IF(E$167=18,T56,IF(E$167=19,U56,IF(E$167=20,V56,IF(E$167=21,W56,IF(E$167=22,X56,IF(E$167=23,Y56,IF(E$167=24,Z56,IF(E$167=25,AA56,IF(E$167=26,AB56,IF(E$167=27,AC56,IF(E$167=28,AD56,IF(E$167=29,AE56,IF(E$167=30,AF56,IF(E$167=31,AG56,IF(E$167=32,AH56,IF(E$167=33,AI56,IF(E$167=34,AJ56,IF(E$167=35,AK56,””)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: This is terrible.  Create and use a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) table instead.

Comment: Note those double quotes in `,AK56,””)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))`, that's actually are not double quotes. It should be `,AK56,"")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))`

Comment: Thanks @tigeravatar. Looks like VLOOKUP will do exactly what I need. It felt like an absurdly long if/then formula...

Comment: @Mrig that did it! somehow my code editor was in rich text mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have run into a function nesting limit. Try the choose function to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
=IF(AND(E167>0,E167<36),OFFSET(B56,0,E167),"")
```

***Note :*** `OFFSET` is a volatile function, see [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) for details.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vlookup or hlookup function can do exactly what you need without righting long nested if statement.

for example you can use:
`=vlookup(E$167,$A1:$B35,2,false)` where $A1:$B35 is the table array containing column A (1-35) and column B its corresponding value.